# How to properly handle conflicting distutils libraries with pip?

Tags: python, pip

After upgrade of `pip` version to `10.0.0`, installation with pip fails when there is a version conflict with a distutils installed package:

```
Cannot uninstall '***'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

This could be for `PyYAML, pyOpenSSL, urllib3, chardet` and so on.

I try to manage this issue by uninstalling corresponding packages such as;

```
python-yaml python-openssl python-urllib3 python-chardet
```

with `apt-get` (Ubuntu) and then install those libraries again with `pip`

However as it might be expected removal by `apt-get` also results removal of many dependent additional system packages which seems not a good practice:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
apt-xapian-index cloud-init landscape-client-ui-install oneconf python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-chardet python-cupshelpers python-debian python-openssl python-pip python-requests python-ubuntu-sso-client python-urllib3 python-yaml sessioninstaller software-center ssh-import-id system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-qt update-manager update-notifier update-notifier-common
```

I also don't want to downgrade `pip` to an older version.

So what is the best practice to handle conflicting distutils libraries with pip?

Ps: I supposed `pip` is for easy management of `Python` libraries but this incident makes it enough complicated.

Comment: There is no the single best solution. Language package managers (like `pip` and `npm`) conflict with OS package managers (`apt` and `rpm`) and there are many ways to resolve conflicts. For some packages you simple remove files/directories manually. For some you remove them with `apt` and reinstall with `pip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtual environment of `Python` might help to handle conflicting libraries even with newer versions of `pip`

#### Setup virtualenv

`Python3` has builtin virtual environment. In case of `Python2`, `virtualenv` can be used for this purpose.

Use following commands to setup `virtualenv`

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
venv_path="${HOME}/py_venv"
mkdir -p "${venv_path}"
virtualenv "${venv_path}"
```

It can be activated by `source` command

```
source "${venv_path}/bin/activate"
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$
```

and can be deactivated by `deactivate` command

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ deactivate
my_user@my_machine:~$
```

#### Confirm paths for python and pip

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ which python
/home/my_user/py_venv/bin/python
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ which pip
/home/my_user/py_venv/bin/pip
```

Be aware by default executing with `sudo` does not point to virtualenv

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ sudo which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

#### Install / uninstall packages with pip

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ pip install ansible
```

Successfully installed in `virtualenv`

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ which ansible
/home/my_user/py_venv/bin/ansible
```

Uninstall a conflicting system package in `virtualenv`

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ pip uninstall urllib3
Skipping urllib3 as it is not installed.
```

Uninstall same package in real environment

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ deactivate
my_user@my_machine:~$ pip uninstall urllib3
Cannot uninstall 'urllib3'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

As it can be seen with the help of `Python` virtual environment, it becomes possible to use newer versions of `pip` to install & uninstall `Python` libraries without touching any system packages.

Comment: Need to activate the virtual environment by `activate path/to/your/virtualenv`. For more information https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script